# Feed Fragment, Mark Murphy Busy Coder Helper

Tags: android

Is anyone familiar with the Mark Murphy tutorial in Busy Coders Guide advance the Feed Fragment tutorial he did?

Well my question is how do you make a dynamic feed in this tutorial meaning that it stays the same all through application. with his the feed url are in hashmaps?

So from his tutorial how would you add a url that would be there each time the application is loaded?

Comment: You probably mean [The Busy Coder's Guide to Advanced Android Development](https://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid/). Note that author _is_ https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware.

Answer (score 1):

[As I replied to your post to the `cw-android` Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/cw-android/browse_frm/thread/abc478ecdc670a90), the five feeds built into FeedFragments already are "the same all through application". While you can add additional feeds, I don't remember adding in any ability to delete feeds.